# List of all tables in database, and number of rows in each one?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Does anyone know what MySQL statement I would use to return results containing a list of all the tables in a database and the number of rows in each one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Table_name,Table_rows FROM 
information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabase'
```

Comment: ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for table 'tables'
Is it safe to grant select to 'tables' for 'myuser', or is there a better/safer way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

show tables - for list of tables

show table status - should give you the name, number of rows, and a list of extra info

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqlshow DBName --count
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PEAR DB shortcuts methods.

```
$db=DB::Connect("mysql://root@localhost/testdb");
$tab=$db->getListOf("tables");
....
$db->tableinfo("table_name");
...
$r=$db->query("select * from table_name");
echo $r->numrows();
echo $r->numcols();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning MySQL and didn't know about the show table status command. Nice One!

As I said, I'm just starting, but already my database has over 2 million rows.

Does the host computer have to find storage for all rows if you

```
select * from table_name
```

Wouldn't it be simpler to say

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

and get only one row in return?